# How can I plus file's info?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm making a new game and I wanna make a coins collector to, later, buy things with those coins. I'm using eclipse.

```
    void save() {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("coins.txt");
        out.write(Integer.toString(nmonedas));
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



void load() {
     StringBuffer texto=new StringBuffer();
     try {
     int c;
     @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    FileReader entrada=new FileReader("coins.txt");
     while((c=entrada.read())!=-1){
     texto.append((char)c);
      }
     }
     catch (IOException ex) {}
     labelshow.setText(texto.toString());

}
```

I have this code but i cant plus the info. NEED HELP PLS

---

Well, the thing is, I'm doing a game in eclipse and I want you to collect coins and keep them in a file.
They are collected perfectly and stored in the file, but when I start the game again I want them to be collected but they add up with the previous ones

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to appending text to a .TXT file. If so, you can use something like this:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("Path to text file here"), "Content".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

I would put the above in a TRY CATCH block.  Also look into PrintWriter as this may be more appopriate to what you need it for as it allows you to continuously write to the file.

Comment: Can i talk with you in private? I have to send this project tomorrow D:

Comment: I am at work buddy - sorry.  If you give me more information; show me the code you tried so far with the code line i mentioned above.